# Fermats theorem, Euler's phi function application

Tags: number-theory

> If $p,q$ are distinct primes and $a$ is any integer,then prove that $$a^{pq} - a^p - a^q + a$$ is divisible by $pq$.

I have tried many times, but failed, please help me

Comment: What attempts have you made so far? If you add them to the question, then people may be able to point out where you are going wrong

Answer (score 3):

Using Fermat we have 
$$
(a^q)^p-a^p-a^q+a\equiv a^q-a-a^q+a\equiv 0\bmod p.
$$
What is the result modulo $q$?